# Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "glossify_taxonomy" plugin does not exist.

Tags: installation

In Drupal 8 when we upload the module we will get this kind of issue very often.

I have installed glossify and its submodule glossify_taxonomy and configured. we have created some content in production.

After some days we felt we don't need glossify module. In our local instance we have uninstalled the module using composer and exported configuration and pushed to production and configuration also imported.

whenever we have try to create content or else try to access existing content we are getting plugin not found exception.

**We have fixed it by first removed all the configuration, deleted all the content and removed the modules from contrib directory**

But in production we can't do this every time. Please suggest how to safely uninstall the module.

**thank you everyone for the answer in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches (if you don't want to reinstall the module's source code to production and work through the same steps to fully uninstall it).

- If you have command line access to the webserver, you could try using [drush to uninstall the module](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/pm/pm-uninstall/) on production. Run `drush pm-uninstall glossify_taxonomy` and then `drush pm-uninstall glossify`
- If that fails, you could schedule a content freeze, download the database to your local instance, and manually set the module as "disabled". Unlike Drupal 7's variables table however, each module does not have it's own row of data.  Instead all module enabled/disabled states are aggregated and saved in the row of data where *cid = core.extension* within both the *config* and *cache-config* tables. To disable the module without fully uninstalling:

  1. load the exported database from prod locally and:
  2. Open ‘config’ table
  3. Search row with ‘core.extension‘
  4. Download Blob object
  5. Unserialize Data (http://www.unserialize.me/ is a quick online tool to serialize and unserialize)
  6. Unset the glossify & glossify_taxonomy modules or remove them from the array.
  7. Serialize Data
  8. Upload Blob object
  9. Save the edited record
  10. Open ‘cache-config’ table and repeat steps 2-8
  11. Export the modified local database
  12. Before making changes on production, keep a backup of the database for quick reversion if needed.
  13. Import the modified local database back to prod
  14. Test to see if you continue to observe the Missing Module warning/error.