# Plugin Not Found Exception

Tags: 8, plugins

I am implementing REST in Drupal 8. I have created a custom plugin for REST resource, enabled the plugin and configured permissions for that REST endpoint.

After few days, I removed the code for plugin without disabling the REST endpoint. I am encountering a plugin not found function for that REST endpoint.

Following this [Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "glossify_taxonomy" plugin does not exist.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/257164/drupal-component-plugin-exception-pluginnotfoundexception-the-glossify-taxonom), I made changes in the config and cache config table. Still I am encountering Plugin not found exception when I click on Permissions and Extend in Menu.

How can I remove this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try these steps

1. drush cex -y actual configs.
2. Find in your config folder yml file rest.resource.{YOUR_RESOURCE_NAME} and delete it.
3. drush cim -y this change, it will be correctly removed from DB.
4. drush cr for sure, and error will miss.

Some related discussion going here 
https://www.drupal.org/project/restui/issues/2889860

Comment: Thanks a lot, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/257164/drupal-component-plugin-exception-pluginnotfoundexception-the-glossify-taxonom this  solved my problem. Plugin error is due to another one.